# listview collapse previous list item

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I'm trying to expand & collapse lists in list view using this code.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (item.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        item.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        item.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Here, if I expand another list the first one stays expanded until I touch/click it again.
Is there a way to collapse the previous list on touch or click of expanding next list item of list view.

Comment: Keep track of the previously touched cell on class level. And when expanding one view, collapse the previous one.

Comment: @ShamasS I tried taking a back variable & then hiding it every next time.
I don't know why it didn't work.